# How to hide arguments from a java process?

Tags: java, process, cmd

I want to hide arguments (password paraphrase) from a running java process (can be seen from command line).

For example, when i type jps -m on cmd, it shows me all the java processes along with their arguments:

Output after running jps -m: 6120 someproject.jar -password

where 6210 is pid.

I need that password to run java process. The problem is if my machine is compromised, someone could read password and can do further damage.

One solution could be storing password in a file locally. But still someone can get it if machine is compromised.

Any ideas how i proceed ?

Thanks in advance.

update1: The password is hashed but still i want it to hide.

Comment: You could use an environment variable, and you might encrypt the key file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would handle this in (for example) a C program would be to write over the argument list supplied to the `main(...)` entry point method.  For more information read this:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/can-other-users-view-the-arguments-passed-to-a-command

Unfortunately, the "overwrite" approach is not available to a Java application.  From pure Java, it is simply not possible.  Even with native code library, it would be difficult to find where in memory the (native) argument vector is stored.

(And besides, there is a small time window in which the arguments are exposed ... before the application erases them.)

---

So your best bet is to pass the secret information another way.  For example, pass the secret info via an environment variable, via a temporary file with access restrictions, or via standard input.